# Creating basic DEM file with flat geometry in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, arcgis-9.3

I want to create a basic DEM file in .ascii format which will just be a rectangular grid and with no slope i.e same elevation at every cell.

Please provide information on how to achieve this.

I am using ArcGIS 9.3.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Create Constant Raster](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=create_constant_raster) tool.

Answer (score 2):

An easy approach would be to create a polygon of your study area, and give that feature the hight that you want as an attribute.

After that use the [Polygon to raster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000030000000) tool to create a raster file, with your hight as the cell value for all cells.  After this, use the [Raster to Ascii](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000005000000) tool to convert the raster to ASCII format.